# Retrieving climate data on "rnoaa" package in R

Tags: r, rnoaa

I am trying to retrieve climate data for a specific `station_ID` on a specific `date`. My dataset contains both elements.

```
for(i in data$date){lapply(data$station_id[i],
                           ghcnd_search,
                           var = "PRCP", 
                           date_min = data$date[i],
                           date_max = data$date[i])}
```

I tried this but to no avail. I would be grateful if someone can help me out.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  I assume that you need only `for` loop or `lapply`

Comment: May be this works for you. `out <- vector('list', nrow(data)); for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) out[[i]] <- ghcnd_search(stationid  = data$station_id[i], var = "PRCP", date_min = data$date[i], date_max = data$date[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the sequence of rows and then use that index to subset the values of 'date' and 'station_id'

```
library(rnoaa)
out <- vector('list', nrow(data))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))){
 out[[i]] <- ghcnd_search(stationid  = data$station_id[i], 
   var = "PRCP", date_min = data$date[i], date_max = data$date[i])
}
```

-output

```
out
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$prcp
# A tibble: 1 x 6
#  id           prcp date       mflag qflag sflag
#  <chr>       <int> <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 AGE00147704    90 1920-01-01 " "   " "   E    


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$prcp
# A tibble: 1 x 6
#  id           prcp date       mflag qflag sflag
#  <chr>       <int> <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 AGE00147704     0 1915-01-01 " "   " "   E
```

---

or using `Map`

```
out1 <- Map(function(x, y) ghcnd_search(stationid = x, var = "PRCP",
         date_min = y, date_max= y), data$station_id, data$date)
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(station_id = c("AGE00147704", "AGE00147704"),
    date = c("1920-01-01", "1915-01-01"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried and getting this;  Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov] server response timeout

Comment: @user13794388 you may need some `Sys.sleep` in between to avoid the error.  anyway, I answered the question asked. thank you